# How to make a Topic editor

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5, xss

I was searching until now and I've got nothing , I want to make a topic Editor in my Laravel project (where the user can write a Rich Text) . I found many JavaScript plugins where the user can create his document and the plugin will create the HTML code in the background

But the problem is that the user can get into the HTML code and change it to add scripts or anything (XSS) so I wanted to know what programmers usually do in such a situation :

- do they filter the requested HTML on the server side (If so Help me with a source or a function)
- will they create a normal text like StackOverFlow then they change the text to HTML on the server `EXP:[img:link]=><img src="link"/>`

So this is my problem and I don't know what to write exactly in google so please help with any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the data server side anyway, so do a HTML processing there and allow only specific tags.

Comment: Thank you , but is there any function to do that , do I have to scan all html tags ?